# How to use new C++ style API in OpenCVSharp code?

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm using OpenCVSharp but currently have half of my code in the C and the other half in the C++ API, I'm trying to port it all to the C++ version to avoid the deprecated API as well as to avoid loading images twice (share `Mat` instead of having one `Mat` and one `CvMat` per image)

Here's the code I had that works :

```
            CvMat distortion = new CvMat(8, 1, MatrixType.F64C1);
            distortion[0, 0] = camera.CameraConfig.k1;
            distortion[1, 0] = camera.CameraConfig.k2;
            distortion[2, 0] = camera.CameraConfig.p1;
            distortion[3, 0] = camera.CameraConfig.p2;
            distortion[4, 0] = camera.CameraConfig.k3;
            distortion[5, 0] = 0;
            distortion[6, 0] = 0;
            distortion[7, 0] = 0;

            CvMat intrinsic = new CvMat(3, 3, MatrixType.F32C1);
            intrinsic[0, 0] = camera.CameraConfig.fx;
            intrinsic[0, 1] = camera.CameraConfig.skew;
            intrinsic[0, 2] = camera.CameraConfig.cx;
            intrinsic[1, 0] = 0;
            intrinsic[1, 1] = camera.CameraConfig.fy;
            intrinsic[1, 2] = camera.CameraConfig.cy;
            intrinsic[2, 0] = 0;
            intrinsic[2, 1] = 0;
            intrinsic[2, 2] = 1;
            Cv.Undistort2(camera.SourceImage, newSourceImage,intrinsic,distortion);
```

And the code (that seemed like an obvious port as I typed it) that doesn't work (I end up with a single colored image of a color that is present in the scene) :

```
            Mat distortion = new Mat(8, 1, MatType.CV_64FC1);
            distortion.Set(0, 0, camera.CameraConfig.k1);
            distortion.Set(1, 0, camera.CameraConfig.k2);
            distortion.Set(2, 0, camera.CameraConfig.p1);
            distortion.Set(3, 0, camera.CameraConfig.p2);
            distortion.Set(4, 0, camera.CameraConfig.k3);
            distortion.Set(5, 0, 0);
            distortion.Set(6, 0, 0);
            distortion.Set(7, 0, 0);

            Mat intrinsic = new Mat(3, 3, MatType.CV_32FC1);
            intrinsic.Set(0, 0, camera.CameraConfig.fx);
            intrinsic.Set(0, 1, camera.CameraConfig.skew);
            intrinsic.Set(0, 2, camera.CameraConfig.cx);
            intrinsic.Set(1, 0, 0);
            intrinsic.Set(1, 1, camera.CameraConfig.fy);
            intrinsic.Set(1, 2, camera.CameraConfig.cy);
            intrinsic.Set(2, 0, 0);
            intrinsic.Set(2, 1, 0);
            intrinsic.Set(2, 2, 1);
            var newSourceImage = camera.SourceImage.Undistort(intrinsic, distortion);
```

Am I wrongly setting the values? Is the porting not that straightforward?

Comment: @Eser because this is C#, as mentioned on the first line i'm using OpenCVSharp (a C# wrapper for OpenCV), OpenCV exposes two APIs (a C and a C++ style API) and both are available in C# through OpenCVSharp, so this is pure C# code, but "in C#" i want to switch from using the C methods to the C++ ones

Comment: Consider to clarify title of your post - it so does not work with "C#" tag... (based on your comment it actually makes sense, but title alone is confusing and *can* cause downvotes/useless comments like this one).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i always thought it was actually frowned upon to note the technology instead of the question in the title as it was the role of tags, seeing how high your reputation is i'll side with that if you're sure it's the right choice but it seemed not to be as the question is "switching from the C to the C++ API) and the technologies are OpenCV/OpenCVSharp/C#. Do you still feel like i should switch?

Comment: Ronan, using tags as tags in title (like "C#: how for working") is indeed frowned upon. But if tag naturally part of the sentence it is fine like "How to use C++ -style API from OnenCVsharp". Current title has no relation to problem discussed in the post when one looks at it - for question like "C->C++" I'd expect some conversation about classes/templates and definitely not C#. Also C++ posts frequently mislabeled with C# tag (that usually fixed quickly, but still first impression is mislabeled post).

Comment: BTW your suggestion "technologies are OpenCV/OpenCVSharp/C#" is definitely on "frowned upon" side... Try to figure out what actual problem you trying to solve and put it as title - see if suggestion in my previous comment aligns with your goal. (Note that I can't really answer your question)

Comment: Which is why i've put the technologies as tafs from the begining. I've already changed the title does this look better?

Comment: I've changed title to include more words/remove what looked like "tag in title" - see if it matches you intention - feel free to roll-back to original (I don't think your edit was improvement over original). Comments will self-destruct sometime soon 10...9...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the difference in your `camera.SourceImage` and `newSourceImage`. In your first snippet you assign `newSourceImage` out of the scope, so I assume you can do something like:

```
newSourceImage = new Mat(new Size(...), MatType.CV_8UC3)
```

But in your second snippet you create it as `var newSourceImage = ...`.
So, it looks like 'undistort' determines your Mat type by itself and does it wrong.

Can you show all initialization, please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this?

I have not used OpenCVSharp, but I use OpenCV in C++ and call it from C#, using a C++/CLI wrapper. Having used EmguCV before, I think consuming OpenCV in C++ is better than through a wrapper, sometimes errors are clearer because you can debug and look at the call stack, and also there's a broader community to help you with OpenCV's C++ and Python APIs.

That being said, from my experience, if you can reach the native code and debug it, it would be the best, so that you can be sure that OpenCV's undistort is actually getting the right parameters. Try enabling native code debugging, but I think you'll need OpenCVSharp's source code too to debug it too.

If this doesn't work, maybe you could look at OpenCV's original undistort method and recreate it using OpenCVSharp. Or maybe undistort the channels separately and merge. Hardly ideal, but you can't fix hidden behaviour, only work around it.

Comment: I haven't solved it no, in the end i droped it thinking it wasn't work the trouble and did my own mini wrapper around the parts of OpenCV i'm interested in in C++/CLI and it's working just fine so far.

Comment: I think that's a good approach. And oh, now it doesn't matter, but you could've also posted this issue on OpenCV's [github](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues?q=is%3Aissue).

Comment: But since i'm not sure on the usage (set?) i'm not even sure there's a bug so i don't think i shoukd post an issue

Comment: `set` usage seems to be fine, I mean, what else could've done with `set`? There are some examples [here](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/blob/f53cbe43e2b88effd7341b810917aa8fcfaaa09e/sample/SamplesCS/Samples/PixelAccess.cs), it has Mat access by operator[] and set. I don't know if the wrapper reflects C++, but at least for `vector` type, set throws exception for invalid position and [] doesn't, so again, I'd guess Mat does the same and your code should be fine. But anyway, I just meant you could ask them.